# 1&1 Mysql connections with JAVA problems

Tags: java, mysql, web, hosting

I made a java program in which users would be automatically inserted/selected lines into/from one mysql database, but could not modify any existing lines, tables, db, or privilages. I got myself a website and hosted it in 1and1.com, but sadly I found out that its a pain(impossible) to have multiple users for one database and to remotly connect to a database.

I was wondering what are my options here?
I suppose the first one would be to get another host that allows me to do this.
The only other option I can think of is that somehow I manage to send from java the information to my website, and then the website to connect to the database. (not an expert in php, html, or what ever i ahve to do (be by embbedding a browser on my GUI or by doing it under the hood).

This is my first attempt to create a program that connects to an online database, so please be nice.

Note: program worked in localhost.
1&1 support useless.

Comment: Call 1&1 support and navigate through the phone system to talk to the **Dedicated Server** support team. Sometimes they don't care if you don't have a dedicated server and they clearly know more than the other support personnel.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'remotely'? End users connecting from their local machines directly to your database?

Comment: Yes, my idea was to have some "safe" way for users to connect to my database. Reading if possible atm. I would like at least to be able to connect myself to a remote database. Maybe even allow some trusted users to connect. Still THIS database in worst case scenario, could be deleted and I wouldnt mind that much (I could have backup on another. Users could just insert info, and then I could copy the info somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all (web)applications that use a database, connect to the database with one database user for the whole application. Having a different database user for each user of the application is an uncommon design.

So, you should configure one database user, which the application uses to read from or write to the database; this database user is independent of the users of your application and is shared by all users of your application. There should not be a one-to-one mapping from application users to database users.

There are different reasons for this. One of them is scalability. Most databases cannot handle thousands of connections at the same time. If you have a web app that allows thousands of concurrent users, you don't want to have a database connection with a unique username for each of those users. Instead you want to use a connection pool with a limited number of database connections; the connections in the pool are reused whenever one of the web app users needs to perform an action that accesses the database.